# How can I make this code shorter using __init__?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, init

This is the code I' ve been working on:

## define the Vehicle class

```
class Vehicle:
    name = ""
    kind = "car"
    color = ""
    value = 100.00
    def description(self):
        desc_str = "%s is a %s %s worth $%.2f." % (self.name, self.color, self.kind, self.value)
        return desc_str
# your code goes here
car1 = Vehicle()
name = "Fer"
kind = "convertible"
color = "red"
value = 60,000.00
car2 = Vehicle()
name = "Jump"
kind = "van"
color = "blue"
value = 10,000.00
# test code
print(car1.description())
print(car2.description())
```

I want to make this shorter using **init** but I haven't succeeded ye

Comment: You don't currently have an `__init__` method at all. Have you tried to create one? [See the end of this section](https://us04web.zoom.us/j/71789462237?pwd=w5a9k5xpnErdUZlWjqObStxKMLYulj.1)

Comment: this code doesn't really do anything at the moment. however, still went ahead and upvoted, cos i'd say a good attempt at it.

Answer (score 2):

If the `__init__` method is simple like this, you could a [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html).

Directly answering your question, would be this:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Vehicle:
    name: str
    kind: str
    color: str
    value: float

    def description(self) -> str:
        return "%s is a %s %s worth $%.2f." % (self.name, self.color, self.kind, self.value)

v1 = Vehicle("Fer", "convertible", "red", 60_000.0)
v2 = Vehicle("Jump", "van", "blue", 10_000.0)
```

---

But there are several improvements you could make to this.

- Limited kinds of vehicle
  Currently, `kind` can be any string, but presumably there are only a limited number of kinds of vehicle, so you could restrict to these. I would use an `Enum`.
- You have to specify everything even if there might be defaults
- Description could be a property
- Using formatted strings (the new standard)

Putting that all together would look like this:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from enum import Enum

class VehicleKind(Enum):
    CAR = "car"
    VAN = "van"
    CONVERTIBLE = "convertible"


@dataclass
class Vehicle:
    name: str
    color: str
    kind: VehicleKind = VehicleKind.CAR
    value: float = 100.0

    @property
    def description(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.name} is a {self.color} {self.kind.value} worth {self.value:.2f}"

v1 = Vehicle("Fer", "red", VehicleKind.CONVERTIBLE, 60_000.0)
v2 = Vehicle("Jump", "blue", VehicleKind.VAN, 10_000.0)

print(Vehicle("Default", "green").description)
# Default is a green car worth 100.00
```

Comment: Great answer to introduce OP to the dataclass decorator!

Comment: Enum member naming conventions I think would usually be `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` instead. So personally, all together, I would design it something like `Vehicle.VAN`. However, nitpicking on naming aside, this does work well and is a good intro to dataclasses as was previously mentioned.

Comment: Good point. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Create an `__init__` function, which takes `self` as an argument + the arguments passed to the instance that you cerate of `Vehicle`:

```py
class Vehicle:    
    def __init__(self, name, kind, color, value):
        self.name = name
        self.kind = kind
        self.color = color
        self.value = value
    
    def description(self):
        desc_str = "%s is a %s %s worth $%.2f" % (self.name, self.color, self.kind, self.value)
        return desc_str
    

# your code goes here
car1 = Vehicle(name = "Fer",
               kind = "convertible",
               color = "red",
               value = 60000)
car2 = Vehicle(name = "Jump",
               kind = "van",
               color = "blue",
               value = 10000)

# test code
print(car1.description())
print(car2.description())
```

You can read more about this in the official Python documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects).

PS: you can remove the variables that you put at the top of the `Vehicle` class as they can be defined in `__init__`.

Comment: Not best practice to set class attributes like that for this case as they are never being used.

Comment: @blueteeth agreed I was in the process of editing my response upon re-reading it. Didn't immediately pick on it when writing my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, name, kind, color, value):
        self.name = name
        self.kind = kind
        self.color = color
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):  # this makes it a string if you want to print something
        return "%s is a %s %s worth $%.2f." % (self.name, self.color, self.kind, self.value)


# your code goes here
car1 = Vehicle(name="Fer", kind="convertible", color="red", value=60000.00)
car2 = Vehicle(name="Jump", kind="van", color="blue", value=10000.00)

# test code
print(car1) # the __str__ makes it so we don't have to call a function for this.
print(car2)
```